# Snapshot is failing to css hash keep changing in Antd

Tags: antd, css-in-js

My CI/CD pipeline is failing because of hash changes `css-dev-only-do-not-override-xxxx`.

```
  <ConfigProvider theme={{ hashed: false }}></ConfigProvider>
```

`hashed:false` didn't really solve in Antd 5.11. CSS hashes are still there?